# matplotlib построить точечную диаграмму с помощью цикла

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Создаю с помощью matplotlib сетку графиков точечных диаграм по двум столбцам. Не могу понять логику построения цикла. Выходит синтаксическая ошибка. Без цикла получается построение сетки. С циклом ошибка, может подскажете, что не так делаю? Как можно построить с циклом сетку графиков?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16), ncols=4, nrows=3, sharex=True)


ax[0][0].scatter(x = gis38['NA_Sales'], y = gis38['Global_Sales'])
ax[0][0].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[0][0].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[0][0].set_title('Sports - Nintendo')

ax[1][0].scatter(x = gis39['NA_Sales'], y = gis39['Global_Sales'])
ax[1][0].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[1][0].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[1][0].set_title('Sports - Take-Two Interactive')

ax[2][0].scatter(x = gis40['NA_Sales'], y = gis40['Global_Sales'])
ax[2][0].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[2][0].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[2][0].set_title('Sports - Electronic Arts')


ax[0][3].scatter(x = gis41['NA_Sales'], y = gis41['Global_Sales'])
ax[0][3].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[0][3].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[0][3].set_title('Sports - Activision')

ax[0][1].scatter(x = gis42['NA_Sales'], y = gis42['Global_Sales'])
ax[0][1].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[0][1].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[0][1].set_title('Platform - Nintendo')


ax[1][1].scatter(x = gis43['NA_Sales'], y = gis43['Global_Sales'])
ax[1][1].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[1][1].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[1][1].set_title('Platform - Take-Two Interactive')

ax[2][1].scatter(x = gis44['NA_Sales'], y = gis44['Global_Sales'])
ax[2][1].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[2][1].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[2][1].set_title('Platform - Electronic Arts')


ax[1][3].scatter(x = gis45['NA_Sales'], y = gis45['Global_Sales'])
ax[1][3].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[1][3].set_ylabel("House Price")
ax[1][3].set_title('Platform - Activision')

ax[0][2].scatter(x = gis46['NA_Sales'], y = gis46['Global_Sales'])
ax[0][2].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[0][2].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[0][2].set_title('Misc - Nintendo')

ax[1][2].scatter(x = gis47['NA_Sales'], y = gis47['Global_Sales'])
ax[1][2].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[1][2].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[1][2].set_title('Misc - Take-Two Interactive')

ax[2][2].scatter(x = gis48['NA_Sales'], y = gis48['Global_Sales'])
ax[2][2].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[2][2].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[2][2].set_title('Misc - Electronic Arts')

ax[2][3].scatter(x = gis49['NA_Sales'], y = gis49['Global_Sales'])
ax[2][3].set_xlabel("NA_Sales")
ax[2][3].set_ylabel("Global_Sales")
ax[2][3].set_title('Misc - Activision')

fig.suptitle("Зависимость общемировых продаж от продаж в Северной Америке для каждой пары (жанр, издатель)",
             y= 0.95)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16), ncols=4, nrows=3, sharex=True)

Genre1 = ['Sports', 'Platform', 'Misc']
Publisher2 = ['Nintendo', 'Take-Two Interactive', 'Electronic Arts', 'Activision']
for i, Genre  in enumerate(Genre1): 
    for j, Publisher in enumerate(Publisher2):
        
        
        data = df[(df['Genre'] == Genre) & (df['Publisher'] == Publisher)['NA_Sales','Global_Sales']
        axs[i][j].scatter(data)
        
        


        
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Невозможно так покрасить точки. Каждая точка на графике отображает пару значений (NA_Sales, Global_Sales) одновременно. Или я не понимаю вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо, поняла!

Comment: А можно сделать с помощью цикла построение графиков? Чтобы меньше писать кода?

Comment: Конечно, это возможно. Вам нужен начальный курс по Питону. Там всё не сложно.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в этой строке кривой синтаксис, не закрыта квадратная скобка как минимум, хотя ругается питон в итоге на следующую строку, ну, так бывает:

```
data = df[(df['Genre'] == Genre) & (df['Publisher'] == Publisher)['NA_Sales','Global_Sales']
```

Правильно выбирать данные нужно бы используя синтаксис `.loc` всё-таки, ну, помимо забытой скобки:

```
data = df.loc[(df['Genre'] == Genre) & (df['Publisher'] == Publisher), ['NA_Sales','Global_Sales']]
```

Можно было и без `.loc` (не рекомендуется), но там синтаксис тоже другой должен был бы быть, как-то так, т.е. вы потеряли 3 скобки, а не одну на самом деле, если я ничего не путаю:

```
data = df[(df['Genre'] == Genre) & (df['Publisher'] == Publisher)][['NA_Sales','Global_Sales']]
                                                                 ^^                           ^
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Получилось

Comment: @Della333 Если вопрос решён, то отметьте подходящий ответ специально галочкой, чтобы ваш вопрос не показывался на сайте как не имеющий ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = df[['Genre', 'Global_Sales']].groupby('Genre')
    .sum().reset_index().sort_values('Global_Sales', ascending = False)
data.head(3)
data1 = df[['Platform', 'Global_Sales']].groupby('Platform')
    .sum().reset_index().sort_values('Global_Sales', ascending = False)
data1.head(4)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 15), nrows = 4, ncols = 3, sharex = True, sharey = True)

genres = ['Action', 'Sports', 'Shooter']
platforms = ['PS2', 'X360', 'PS3', 'Wii']

for i, platform in enumerate(platforms):
    for j, genre in enumerate(genres):
        data = df[(df['Platform'] == platform) & (df['Genre'] == genre)]
            .groupby('Year')[['NA_Sales', 'Global_Sales']].sum().reset_index()
        ax = axs[i][j]
        ax = sns.scatterplot(data = data, x = 'NA_Sales', y = 'Global_Sales', ax = ax, hue = 'Year')
        ax.set_title(f'Продажи платформы {platform} жанра игр {genre}')
        
        if j == 0:
            ax.set_ylabel('Продано во всем мире')
        
        if i == len(platforms) - 1:
            ax.set_xlabel('Продано в северной Америке')
fig.suptitle('зависимость общемировых продаж от продаж в Северной Америке для каждой пары (жанра, платформы)', y = 0.95)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]